# Select Minimum difference of summary of two columns in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need help building a query, which returns the Minimum difference between Value + another Value from same table and the other ID that gave the result (plus the sum can't be sum of the value itself)

Table:

```
ID    Value
1     1        
2     2        
3     5        
4     -10      
5     -5
6     3
7     -15
```

Expected result:

```
ID    Value    MinDif   IDofTheOtherValue
1     1        3        2                   <-- MinDif = 1 + 2 (ID 1 + ID 2)
2     2        3        1                   <-- MinDif = 2 + 1 (ID 2 + ID 1)
3     5        0        5                   <-- MinDif = 5 + -5 (ID 3 + ID 5)
4     -10      -5       3                   <-- MinDif = -10 + 5 (ID 4 + ID 3)
5     -5       0        3                   <-- MinDif = -5 + 5 (ID 5 + ID 3)
6     3        -2       5                   <-- MinDif = 3 + -5 (ID 6 + ID 5)
7     -15      -10      3                   <-- MinDif = -15 + 5 (ID 7 + ID 3)
```

Here's a query to create the table:

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE(ID int, Value int)
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES (1, 1), (2,2), (3, 5), (4, -10), (5, -5), (6, 3), (7, -15)
```

And here's what I have tried, but this gives an SQL error (Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.)

```
SELECT m.ID, MIN(ABS(m.Value + (SELECT m2.Value FROM @myTable m2)))
FROM @myTable m
```

Comment: Have you considered JOIN statement on the table itself ?

Comment: I can't follow your expected result ....

Comment: I Edited the expected results to clarify what i'm trying to get

Comment: simsim: Tried that but no success - got some other error that i cannot reference outer table in aggregate function..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is giving your required results:

```
with diffRank as
(
  select ID = t1.ID
    , minDif = t1.value + t2.value
    , IDofTheOtherValue = t2.ID
    , diffRank = row_number() over (partition by t1.ID order by abs(t1.value + t2.value), t2.ID)
  from @myTable t1
    inner join @myTable t2 on t1.ID <> t2.ID
)
select ID
  , minDif
  , IDofTheOtherValue
from diffRank
where diffRank = 1
order by ID;
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/15134).

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by myself. Here's the Select clause:

```
SELECT tab.ID, tab.Value, test.*    
FROM @myTable tab
OUTER APPLY 
(SELECT TOP 1 ID AS [AnotherID], [SUM]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT m.ID, m2.ID AS [ID2], m.Value + m2.Value AS [SUM]
        FROM @myTable m
        JOIN @myTable m2 ON m2.ID <> m.ID       
    ) apu WHERE ID2 = tab.ID ORDER BY ABS([SUM])) test
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle I would do:

```
select x.id, (select min(abs(x.value + y.value)) from my_table y),
       (select first value (y.id) over (order by abs(x.value + y.value))
          from my_table y)
 from my_table x
```

think of something similar in TSQL

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. it should work.

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE(ID int, Value int)
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES (1, 1), (2,2), (3, 5), (4, -10), (5, -5), (6, 3), (7, -15)

SELECT C.ID, C.Value
, C.Value + (SELECT TOP 1 E.Value FROM @myTable E WHERE C.AbsMinDif = ABS(C.Value + E.Value) ORDER BY E.ID) MinDif
, (SELECT TOP 1 F.ID FROM @myTable F WHERE C.AbsMinDif = ABS(C.Value + F.Value) ORDER BY F.ID) IDofTheOtherValue
FROM (

SELECT A.ID, MIN(A.Value) Value, MIN(ABS(A.Value + B.Value)) AbsMinDif   
FROM @myTable A
CROSS JOIN @myTable B 
WHERE A.ID <> B.ID
GROUP BY A.ID 

) C
```